# How can I make a Joomla module show live data?

Tags: php, joomla, module

I have made a small Joomla module that gets data from an external API and shows it in the module. The module is very basic, containing only the mod_modulename.php, helper.php (with one function fetching the data) and the tmpl/default.php showing the data. The data is continuously changing on the external site, and I would like to make the module live so that it gets new data every 10th second and redraws the module. Can this be done, and if so - how?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this for input:

```
https://github.com/BabDev/Tweet-Display-Back/releases
```